# why my fckeditor is not loading in my web page while working correctly in my local host?

Tags: php

I have a CMS that uses fckeditor , and it works so good on my local host

but when I uploaded my CMS on to a server it caused a problem which is not identifying my fckeditor ?!

I don't know why is this ?! can anybody tell me the reason for such problem so I can fix it

Best Regards

Comment: Any cross-domain issues at play here? Otherwise maybe drop us a line of code or two, or a link, or some error debug spam?

Comment: Maybe if you provide us more details like what server side tech you use, how you include the fck js in the html and all that :) we could helpt you..

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description of the problem. Are you sure that you have uploaded the scripts? Are the folders where you have put the scripts correctly mapped? Which CMS are you using. Try to tell us some more details about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS is Joomla, then there is a chance that it will show some warnings.

If you can give more details, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, i bet you used hard coded paths of your local machine. Instead of using relative paths.

But we need more info to figure out what is wrong.